# Why Do People Add a Reference To XLA's Dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba

Just wondering why projects like solver.xla get added via VBA

I ve seen a number of projects do this in the past - What does it buy you that adding it via the menu does not.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to do it programatically than to try to instruct the user how to add it using the menu, especially when you consider the interface differences between excel 2003 and 2007.

Comment: I'd also add that XLAs cost time to load up. If you have quite a few you might feel the need to optimise and only load the ones that are required for a particular task rather than everything in one go.